# find duplicates by tuple index in list and randomly keep some

Tags: python, list, indexing, tuples

I have a list as follows:

```
[(1, 3, 0.0), (1, 4, 0.0), (3, 4, 0.0),(1,3,0.8),(1,2,0.8),(1,1,1)]
```

Is there a way to find the elements that all have 0.0 in index 2 of the tuple in an efficient way? So, I would want to make a list

```
[(1, 3, 0.0), (1, 4, 0.0), (3, 4, 0.0),(1,3,0.8),(1,2,0.8)]
```

I then want to randomly choose one of the 0.0 and one of the 0.8 to keep.

Basically, I want to find a list of duplicates and keep one element from each duplicate based on index 2 in the tuple.

I wanted more of an efficient solution since there could be hundreds of thousands of elements in the list and many duplicates. I know how to do this inefficiently with for loops, but struggled to think of a very efficient solution. Thanks!

Comment: "Map" division on the tuple and "keep" the ones that create a division by zero error via try catch. That would be linear, yes? Map and keep in quotes to imply the concept and construction respectively, not necessarily the function.

Comment: Try to be more clear and eliminate the noise in question. What are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1]: x = [(1, 3, 0.0), (1, 4, 0.0), (3, 4, 0.0),(1,3,0.8),(1,2,0.8),(1,1,1)]

In [2]: y = [item for item in x if item[2] == 0.0 or item[2] == 0.8]

In [3]: y
Out[3]: [(1, 3, 0.0), (1, 4, 0.0), (3, 4, 0.0)]

In [6]: import random

In [7]: random_item = random.choice(y)

In [8]: random_item
Out[8]: (3, 4, 0.0)
```

random_item = random.choice(y)

This is a list comprehension, it makes a new list based on an old one after checking for a condition (here, if the position 2 item is equal to 0.0)

http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/

Comment: right but this is an arbitrary case, like I want to keep one of each duplicate

Comment: Someone downvoted the question because it isn't possible to answer. Do you want to keep all items with 0.0 in position 2, or do you want to keep all items that have duplicates?

Comment: I want to find a list of duplicates and keep one element from each duplicate based on index 2 in the tuple. Sorry let me clarify that above

Answer (score 1):

Use map to get all the 3rd items and then loop through each item and call list.count(item) method to check count of items.

```
list1 = [(1, 3, 0.0), (1, 4, 0.0), (3, 4, 0.0), (1, 3, 0.8), (1, 2, 0.8), (1, 1, 1)]

list2 = [item for item in list1 if map(lambda x: x[2], list1).count(item[2]) > 1]
```